# Implicit list operations for Seq, Array, and Iterator that return the lists self type

Tags: scala

This is my container type.

```
trait Container[Repr] { self: Repr =>
  def doSomething(): Repr
}

case class IntContainer(value: Int) extends Container[IntContainer] {
  override def doSomething(): IntContainer = IntContainer(value + 1)
}

// IntContainer correctly returns self type
val res: IntContainer = IntContainer(10).doSomething()
```

These are my implicits for lists of the above container type.

```
object Implicits {

  implicit class GenTraversableLikeMonadOps[C <: Container[C], T](containers: GenTraversableLike[C, T]) {
    def doAllTheThings[That]()(implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[T, C, That]): That = 
      containers.map(_.doSomething())
  }

  implicit class ArrayMonadOps[C <: Container[C]](containers: Array[C]) extends GenTraversableLikeMonadOps(containers)

}
```

---

`Seq`, `SeqView`, and `Array` all return the container self type and the list self type.

```
import Implicits._
val seq: Seq[IntContainer] = Seq(IntContainer(0)).doAllTheThings()
val seqView: SeqView[IntContainer,_] = Seq(IntContainer(0)).view.doAllTheThings()
val array: Array[IntContainer] = Array(IntContainer(0)).doAllTheThings()
```

Iterator does not as it does not extend `GenTraversableLike`

```
import Implicits._
val iter: Iterator[IntContainer] = Seq(IntContainer(0)).iterator.doAllTheThings() // Cannot resolve symbol doAllTheThings
```

---

Can I do this in a way such that `doAllTheThings()` returns the source list's self type without duplicating all of `GenTraversableLikeMonadOps` to handle the `Iterator` case?

Comment: Can you use `GenTraversableOnce` instead of `GenTraversableLike` as a parameter for implicit class?

Comment: @rumoku I don't think so?  The key to `GenTraversableLike[C,T]` is that `T` is the representative type for the list.  `GenTraversableOnce` doesn't have that.  There may be another way to structure it so that I can use `GenTraversableOnce`, but I don't know what that would look like.